# Third Party Analysis Service Equivalent Component for SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server-express, ssas, olap

As far as I know, the SQL Server Analysis Service (SSAS) is NOT supported by SQL Server Express Edition (2005/2008/2008R2). Does anyone know if there is any third party SSAS equivalent component / service / system (free or commercial) that does the same job?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've several Olap servers in the market, check the wikipage : [OLAP Server comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_OLAP_Servers)

Amongs them you've [icCube](http://www.iccube.com/) as a In-Memory OLAP server with a community edition. If you ever wonder about what is going on behind an MDX query do not miss the [MDX Debugger and Profiler](http://www.iccube.com/products/iccube/mdx-ide)

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion. I'll give it a go and come back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your requirements: if you need a space to store your multidimensional data you could use [offline cubes](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/about-offline-cube-files-HP005247908.aspx). This is useful to release information to your final clients through MDX Queries or the pivot table component.

Comment: Hi Noe,

I didn't explain the question very well. What I need is a SSAS equivalent component, which can be used on SQL Server Express Edition (2005/2008/2008R2).

But, thanks so much for your comments anyway.